# pool.query is not working with async/await

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, pool

I am new to nodejs trying to read data from mysql using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) library. I am using express framework.

here is the code in my router/index.js file

```
router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(query);
  let data = await query();
  console.log(data);
  res.send();
});
```

code to read data from db (There is no issue in connecting to db).

```
const query = async (table, fields ) => {
    try {
        const results = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM country limit 1');
        return results
    } catch(err) {
        return err;
    }
}
```

The following is getting logged by console.log(data)

```
<ref *1> Query {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _callback: undefined,
  _callSite: Error
      at Pool.query (/Users/siva/Projects/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:199:23)
      at query (/Users/siva/Projects/api/db/index.js:4:36)
      at /Users/siva/Projects/api/routes/index.js:7:20
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/siva/Projects/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
      at next (/Users/siva/Projects/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
      at Route.dispatch (/Users/siva/Projects/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/siva/Projects/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
      at /Users/siva/Projects/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
      at Function.process_params (/Users/siva/Projects/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
      at next (/Users/siva/Projects/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10),
  _ended: false,
  _timeout: undefined,
  _timer: Timer { _object: [Circular *1], _timeout: null },
  sql: 'SELECT * FROM country limit 1',
  values: undefined,
  typeCast: true,
  nestTables: false,
  _resultSet: null,
  _results: [],
  _fields: [],
  _index: 0,
  _loadError: null,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

Can someone please help me to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mysql` library on NPM does not support promises and thus does not work with `await`.  You would need one of several wrappers that implement promise support for mysql or make your own.  A popular module on NPM is a fork named `mysql2` (and they are now coordinating with the mysqljs organization to share common code with the `mysql` project).  With `mysql2` you can do:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
```

Then, you can use `async/await` with mysql calls.